# bootstrap modal and mmenu menu clashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mmenu

I'm designing a site using bootstrap and mmenu libraries. I'm trying to add a bootstrap modal that **opens when clicking a button in mmenu**.

The modal doesn't close when clicking close, pressing ESC and clicking outside the modal.

I tried writing  a page with the same modal and mmenu, where the modal opens by clicking a button on the **page**, not in the mmenu, and both worked fine.

I tried a mmenu popup that appears when the button inside the mmenu is clicked, but had the same problem.

I'd be happy with a generic answer as well;
Where problems with these two libraries can arise, and how to get around them. Or how to debug the code so that I can figure out the solution myself. I tried checking the Console in Chrome but there were no errors there. I don't know how to check any further.

I added my code just in case someone who is familiar with the mmenu and bootstrap libraries has a specific answer. Thank you all for your effort.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <link href="CSS/jquery.mmenu.themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/jquery.mmenu.positioning.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <button type ="button"><a href="#welcomeMenu">Menu</a></button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav id="welcomeMenu" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
            <div>
                <ul class="vertical">
                    <li> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                             Launch demo modal
                        </button>
                    </li>                       
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#welcomeMenu").mmenu({
                extensions: ["theme-dark", "border-full", "multiline", "pagedim-white"],
                offCanvas: {
                    position: "right",
                    zposition: "front"
                }
            });                                         
        });    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AhnJaeHee/okkf2bsr/15/)

Comment: let me know if this code is online,. i would like to have your CSS and js path,.

Comment: @PunitGajjar, I have a folder called CSS with all the css files and a folder called JS with all the js files. It's not online. all the css and js files are mmenu's or bootstrap's.

Comment: Please Create jsfiddle for this.

Comment: I'm willing to bet your jQuery scripts are clashing. Check your dev console for errors.

Comment: may be because of conflict ...see if you have included `bootstrap.js` more than once

Comment: yeah . may be conflict with this .

<script src="JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>

Comment: @DrewKennedy, Of course they are clashing. That is problem I need to solve. I checked my console and there are no errors, by the way.

Comment: too many links, too heavy - too many conflicts

Comment: *Of course they are clashing. That is problem I need to solve* Then maybe that should be the question in your OP and not 10 comments below it.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra, I've added a fiddle to the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

instead

> Remove z-index:1 in row 69 of this file "CSS/jquery.mmenu.all.css"

set z-index in your main css file to auto

```
.mm-slideout { z-index:auto;}
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of changing something in jquery.mmenu.all.css you could include the following in your own css-files:

```
body.modal-open .mm-slideout{
    z-index:inherit;
}
```

Comment: By far easiest solution. Watch the typo though inherit*

Comment: Oh, you are right - i corrected it :) thanks for your hint

Answer (score 3):

Remove `z-index:1` in row 69 of this file "CSS/jquery.mmenu.all.css"

```
.mm-slideout{
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .4s ease;
     transition:-webkit-transform .4s ease;
     transition:transform .4s ease;
     transition:transform .4s ease,-webkit-transform .4s ease;
     z-index:1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your codes is fine and modal can launch and close when button close clicked. I've already tested. the problem is in your `**bootstrap version**`.

I see you use bootstrap.css not min.css. If you feel you have fast speed connection as well as your hosting, there will be no problem. otherwise, use with `min`.

BTW, I use `v3.1.0 (min.js/min.css)` and `jQuery v2.1.1`

Comment: I downloaded bootstrap.min again from bootstrap's site and replaced the one in the project with the new one. The modal still doesn't work for me.

Comment: did the clash can solve your problem? what version are you using now? including, css, js and jquery? (the three is a must)

Comment: I'm using the latest bootstrap and mmenu version, as I just downloaded it this week. jquery is 1.11.3 as you can see in my code,

Comment: try to remove these links first. <br />
`<link href="CSS/jquery.mmenu.themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/jquery.mmenu.positioning.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="JS/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>` to see if there's a conflict

Comment: I need those links for my mmenu. They are vital.

Comment: It does work when I don't include them. That is my problem. I know that there is a conflict. I want to know how to solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101782/discussion-between-herman-nz-and-rosa).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working perfectly, i have tested this.
bellow is the Fiddle to check.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav id="welcomeMenu" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
        <div>
            <ul class="vertical">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log in</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Continue as guest</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <!--a place for tips-->
        <div class="col xs-12 hidden-xs col-sm-3 ">
        </div>       
        <!--a place for text-->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Welcome.</h1><br />
                <small>We are glad to see you here.</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#welcomeMenu").mmenu({
                extensions: ["theme-dark", "border-full", "multiline", "pagedim-white"],
                offCanvas: {
                    position: "right",
                    zposition: "front"
                }
            });                                         
        });
```

Here's the work modal: http://jsfiddle.net/okkf2bsr

Comment: No it doesn't. If you look at your fiddle you'll see that my mmenu is showing. it is not supposed to show. your not using the mmenu libraries, which are causing the problem I want to solve.

Comment: okey, the issue is with z-index.
add `.mm-slideout{z-index: 9999;}` this css
check below fiddle, and let me know if this is working or not.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvwn1f5a/)

Comment: I saw youre fiddle, but there is only the modal there. Not a mmenu. Please see my updated question.

Comment: can you create your fiddle and send me link so i can debug there?

Comment: here you go. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AhnJaeHee/okkf2bsr/15/). In the fiddle I have slightly different problems with them. You'll see.

Comment: here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dg6fcw58/). updated fiddle. in this you haven't call `data-target` and `data-model` attribute and also there is `z-index` issue.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. The first time I clicked **Menu** the modal opened. The second time Both opened and I couldn't close either of them.

Answer (score 1):

i had a same problem before . 
so what i did.

i add the below code in jquery.

```
 // Call Business logo modal.
                $('#myModal_business').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    show: false
                });
```

then after on button click through jquery you can close or open the modal.
like this

```
$(".buttonclass").click( function() {
     $('#myModal_business').modal('show');

});
```

To hide the modal

```
$('#myModal_business').modal('hide');
```

Comment: I used your code, and the modal still doesn't close. What do you mean you had the same issue? My problem is clashing between mmenu libraries and bootstrap libraries.

Comment: try send us your css and js files.